# exception in running hibernate application

Tags: java, hibernate

i am trying to run hibernate application but an exception occurs .. here is my code ..any suggestions .. thanks in advance

`hibernate.cfg.xml`:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>

<!-- Related to the connection START -->
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver </property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb </property>
<property name="connection.user">root </property>
<property name="connection.password">root</property>
<!-- Related to the connection END -->

<!-- Related to hibernate properties START -->
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<property name="dialet">org.hibernate.dialect.MYSQLDialect</property>
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
<!-- Related to hibernate properties END-->

<!-- Related to mapping START-->
<mapping resource="user.hbm.xml" />
<!-- Related to the mapping END -->

</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

`user.hbm.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hibernate-mapping>

<class name="DataProvider" table="user_info">

<id name="user_id" column="id">
<genereator class="assigned" />
</id>

<property name="vuser_name" column="name"/>
<property name="user_address" column="address"/>
</class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

`DataProvider.java`:

```
public class DataProvider {
    private int user_id;
    private String user_name;
    private String user_address;
    public int getUser_id() {
        return user_id;
    }
    public void setUser_id(int user_id) {
        this.user_id = user_id;
    }
    public String getUser_name() {
        return user_name;
    }
    public void setUser_name(String user_name) {
        this.user_name = user_name;
    }
    public String getUser_address() {
        return user_address;
    }
    public void setUser_address(String user_address) {
        this.user_address = user_address;
    }


}
```

`DataInsertion.java`:

```
public class DataInsertion {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DataInsertion().insertInfo();

    }

    public void insertInfo(){
        Configuration con = new Configuration();
        con.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory sf = con.buildSessionFactory();
        Session session = sf.openSession();

        DataProvider provider = new DataProvider();
        provider.setUser_id(121);
        provider.setUser_name("name");
        provider.setUser_address("adress");

        Transaction tr = (Transaction) session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(provider);
        System.out.println("Object Saved");
        try {
            tr.commit();
        } catch (SecurityException | HeuristicMixedException | HeuristicRollbackException | RollbackException
                | SystemException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        session.close();
        sf.close();


    }

}
```

and the exception is

> Mar 20, 2016 12:49:01 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager 
>       INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
>       Mar 20, 2016 12:49:01 PM org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.stax.LocalXmlResourceResolver resolveEntity
>       WARN: HHH90000012: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping instead.  Support for obsolete DTD/XSD namespaces may be removed at any time.
>       Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.boot.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document: user.hbm.xml (RESOURCE)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.InputStreamXmlSource.doBind(InputStreamXmlSource.java:46)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.UrlXmlSource.doBind(UrlXmlSource.java:36)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.bind(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:59)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.addResource(MetadataSources.java:274)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.spi.MappingReference.apply(MappingReference.java:70)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:413)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:692)
>           at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:724)
>           at DataInsertion.insertInfo(DataInsertion.java:22)
>           at DataInsertion.main(DataInsertion.java:15)
>       Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.MappingException: Unable to perform unmarshalling at line number 9 and column 32. Message: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'genereator'. One of '{"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/hbm":meta, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/hbm":column, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/hbm":type, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/hbm":generator}' is expected. : origin(user.hbm.xml)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.AbstractBinder.jaxb(AbstractBinder.java:177)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.MappingBinder.doBind(MappingBinder.java:61)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.AbstractBinder.doBind(AbstractBinder.java:102)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.AbstractBinder.bind(AbstractBinder.java:57)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.InputStreamXmlSource.doBind(InputStreamXmlSource.java:43)
>           ... 10 more
>       Caused by: javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
>        - with linked exception:
>       [org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 9; columnNumber: 32; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'genereator'. One of '{"http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/hbm":meta, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/hbm":column, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/hbm":type, "http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/hbm":generator}' is expected.]
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.handleStreamException(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(Unknown Source)
>           at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(Unknown Source)
>           at org.hibernate.boot.jaxb.internal.AbstractBinder.jaxb(AbstractBinder.java:171)
>           ... 14 more

Comment: there are bunch of misspells in your config files, e. g. `genereator` instead of `generator`, `dialet` instead of `dialect` and maybe more. So no surprise it cannot run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in your user.hbm.xml. You wrote "genereator" instead of "generator". Fix it and it should work.

Comment: an error in this line appears "Transaction tr = (Transaction) session.beginTransaction();"

Comment: Post the stacktrace please.